# What does current research tell us about addictive behaviors in games?

Tags: motivation, addiction

I'm creating a game, and I would like to know what research I can consult to make it more "addicting".

The game is a casual one, like Candy Crush, Angry Birds, etc

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, I know there's been a lot of work done on it, I just don't have any references handy.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent I can find is an **Open Access** paper from May this year:

Kim, D., & Lee, J. (2021). Addictive Internet Gaming Usage among Korean Adolescents before and after the Outbreak of the COVID-19 Pandemic: A Comparison of the Latent Profiles in 2018 and 2020. *International Journal of Environmental Research and Public Health, 18*(14), 7275. https://doi.org/10.3390/ijerph18147275

Other than that, there is:

Wegmann, E., & Brand, M. (2020). Cognitive correlates in gaming disorder and social networks use disorder: A comparison. *Current Addiction Reports, 7*, 356-364. https://doi.org/10.1007/s40429-020-00314-y